Problem while using Firebase cloud functions in Unity: request data always empty
I'm trying to run official quickstart example of Firebase Cloud Functions for Unity engine. The parameter data (dictionary of objects) passed when calling function from unity is always empty. I tried different Firebase SDK versions, but the problem is always there. I have no idea what the problem could be, please help.
Here is the code in Unity:
void Start()
{
        StartCoroutine(AddNumbers(7, 7));
}

protected IEnumerator AddNumbers(int firstNumber, int secondNumber) {
        var functions = FirebaseFunctions.GetInstance(FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance);
        var func = functions.GetHttpsCallableFromURL("https://getnumbers-dxhi3lnaew-uc.a.run.app");
        var data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        data["firstNumber"] = firstNumber;
        data["secondNumber"] = secondNumber;
        var task = func.CallAsync(data).ContinueWithOnMainThread((callTask) => {
            if (callTask.IsFaulted) {
                // The function unexpectedly failed.
                Debug.Log("FAILED!");
                Debug.Log(String.Format("  Error: {0}", callTask.Exception));
                return;
            }

            // The function succeeded.
            var result = (IDictionary)callTask.Result.Data;
            Debug.Log(String.Format("AddNumbers: {0}", result["operationResult"]));
        });
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => task.IsCompleted);
}

Cloud function code:
'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

// Adds two numbers to each other.
exports.getNumbers = functions.https.onCall((data) => {
  // Numbers passed from the client.
  const firstNumber = data.firstNumber;
  const secondNumber = data.secondNumber;

  // Checking that attributes are present and are numbers.
  if (Number.isFinite(firstNumber) || !Number.isFinite(secondNumber)) {
    // Throwing an HttpsError so that the client gets the error details.
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', '!The function ' +
        'must be called with two arguments "firstNumber" and "secondNumber" ' +
        'which must both be numbers.');
  }

  // returning result.
  return {
    firstNumber: firstNumber,
    secondNumber: secondNumber,
    operator: '+',
    operationResult: firstNumber + secondNumber,
  };
});


Do you get the same behaviour using GetHttpsCallable("getNumbers") instead of GetHttpsCallableFromURL? This simple swap assumes your FirebaseApp instance is set to the same region as your Cloud Function. See GetInstance(FirebaseApp app, string region) for details how to override region as needed.

My functions at the "us-central1" region, I also tried to call like this:
var functions = FirebaseFunctions.GetInstance(FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance, "us-central1");
var func = functions.GetHttpsCallable("getNumbers");
still the same error

You have a typo on this line: if (Number.isFinite(firstNumber) || !Number.isFinite(secondNumber)) {. One check confirms a value is a finite number, the other check confirms a value is not a finite number. So if your function gets the values properly (both are numbers) or if it doesn't get them (both are undefined), the check fails in both cases. I think you are missing an !, fix that and follow puf's answer and you should be back online.

The argument to the Cloud Function is actually the entire request object, and the data you pass in the C# code is in a data property in there.
So:
exports.getNumbers = functions.https.onCall((request) => {
  // Numbers passed from the client.
  const firstNumber = request.data.firstNumber;
  const secondNumber = request.data.secondNumber;
  ...


Also see the Firebase documentation on callable functions, which has example showing this.

Thanks, I tried it, but error is still the same. I totally removed functions from firebase console and deployed again - not helped...

First off: did you read the documentation I linked, and (from that) does it make sense that you need to get the value from request.data? There may be more problems in the code you shared, but this was definitely one of them. --- For troubleshooting further problems, you'll want to add some logging to the Cloud Function to see what it does receive.

Thanks for your help, the problem was solved. Seems that it's not possible to use custom parameters like "firstNumber" anymore, all data should be in "text" parameter.
